# How to disable WebStorm missing comma inspection

Tags: webstorm

I would like to disable or edit missing comma in objects.

Image:

[image]

I didn't find any topics. Only about semicolons. I also tried to browse all inspections but without success.

**UPDATE** and propably solution:

i found out that there isn't propably special inspection just for commas only. This type of inspection (missing comma) is using type of warning called 'Error'. So you can edit all these 'Errors' globally. This is propably only the one solution you can try... In settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General, then Errors and Warnings > Error, you can edit Foreground, Background and so on. You can also disable these settings so it will not show up ever again. (be carefull, this will affect all inspections using that Error type)

Comment: you must make sure that Who generate this error? Such as TsLint, and then disable it in the Editor->Inspection. However, I don't understand why you want to do this?

Comment: @XinMeng well, i was thinking and it would be better to edit it so it will display as error or in better case i will style it on my own.. i always forget to add comma at the end of the line and this is happening like 10 times per day. I am using Polymer where is almost everything object typed. So commas are everywhere and if you forget one, you have to reload page once more.. (less time to develop, more time to waste)